# How to ask Mathematica to express variables in terms of each other in an implicit function

Tags: equation-solving, functions

How to ask Mathematica to give $y$ in terms of $x$  in this function? Is there a way to obtain a closed form expression for $y$ in terms of $x$?

$x=\frac{\left(y^4-1\right) \left(\coth (2 y)-\frac{1}{\sinh (2 y)}\right)}{y^7-3 y^4}$

($x$ and $y$ are greater than zero)

Solve and Reduce do not work in this case.

Comment: You have a complicated transcendental equation, you should not expect to be able to find a symbolic inverse. The best you can do is to invert the equation numerically. Over what range are you hoping to work with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[y_] = (y^4 - 1) (Coth[2 y] - 1/Sinh[2 y])/(y^7 - 3 y^4);
```

Graphically, the inverse is

```
ParametricPlot[{f[y], y}, {y, -10, 10},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, y}),
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

[`InverseFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction.html) will provide one branch

```
g[x_] := InverseFunction[f][x]

Plot[g[x], {x, -0.1, 0.15},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, y}),
 PlotRange -> {-10, 10},
 ImageSize -> 500,
 Epilog -> Inset[
   Plot[g[x], {x, -0.1, 0.15},
    Frame -> True],
   {0.08, -5}]]
```

[image]

Numerically finding the inverse

```
g2[x_?NumericQ] := y /. NSolve[x == f[y], y, Reals]

ListPlot[
 Flatten[Table[{x, #} & /@ g2[x],
   {x, -0.1, 0.15, 0.005}], 1],
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, y})]
```

[image]